# Group DataTable by some columns and remove repeated values?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable in my Winforms application that contains data like this:

```
| ItemName | ItemNo |   ItemValue
     B         1            1,4
     B         1            1,9
     B         1            2,2
     A         2            2,0
     A         2            2,7
     A         2            3,1
     C         3            1,3
     C         3            1,5
     C         3            2,1
```

How can i make my DataTable to show in a DataGridView values like this?:

```
| ItemName | ItemNo |   ItemValue
     B         1            1,4
                            1,9
                            2,2
     A         2            2,0
                            2,7
                            3,1
     C         3            1,3
                            1,5
                            2,1
```

Like grouping and removing the repeated values from the datatable and inserting empty values maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a loop like this (`dt` is the `DataTable`):

```
string currentName="", currentNo="";
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     if (row["ItemName"].ToString() == currentName
          && row["ItemNo"].ToString() == currentNo)
     {
         row["ItemName"] = "";
         row["ItemNo"] = "";
     }
     else
     {
         currentName = row["ItemName"].ToString();
         currentNo = row["ItemNo"].ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow to put two empty spaces because when i change the first one then the next is compared with an empty space and it doesn't set to empty too.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy you are right sorry, I couldn't think that.I updated my answer try it now.